# While Creating a new profile on SVN 6.6 on MAC OS X

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn

I am pressing add button.
Then After Selecting  HTTP as a protocol,I have not provided url
I am setting Server NAme : any

### And Repository Path as : Local folder on  My PC

On next detail window I am login and setting user name and password 
But error occurred like 
I have got an ERROR Connection
That "UNKNOWN HOST OPTIONS REQUEST FAILED on repository path "
If I select any other protocol then also then also error is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install SVN software "**Collabnet Subversion Edge** " on your server to which your local machine is connected ..

or You can Create Repository online and can access from anywhere ..

**http://unfuddle.com/accounts/plans**